# Action hook for custom tax edit

Tags: hooks

So, i have a function in my template file functions.php which cache a search form that contain a custom taxonomie terms. I want to flush cache (or delete one cache group) when I add/delete/edit terms of a specific taxonomie.

Is it possible? maybe with do_action, but for which hook?
thx

Answer (score 14):

Look at `wp-includes/taxonomy.php`. The actions are:

```
do_action( "create_term",       $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy );
do_action( "created_term",      $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy );
do_action( "edited_term",       $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy );
do_action( 'delete_term',       $term,    $tt_id, $taxonomy, $deleted_term );
do_action( "create_$taxonomy",  $term_id, $tt_id );
do_action( "created_$taxonomy", $term_id, $tt_id );
do_action( "edited_$taxonomy",  $term_id, $tt_id );
do_action( "delete_$taxonomy",  $term,    $tt_id, $deleted_term );
```

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for `created_term`, `edited_term` and `delete_term`. Each callback accepts 3 parameters:

```
function wpse_created_term( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ) {
}    
function wpse_edited_term( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ) {
}    
function wpse_delete_term( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ) {
}    

add_action( 'created_term', 'wpse_created_term', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'edited_term', 'wpse_edited_term', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'delete_term', 'wpse_delete_term', 10, 3 );
```